# angular for loop making http call - wait for previous call to finish before making next

Tags: angular, api, loops, http, for-loop

hi I have a for loop making http calls like this :  The problem is each http call is invoking a database stored proc which is checking max value of index, increment by 1  and then insert into the table. The for loop when started, for first api call, this.startProcess(..), hit the databse, get max value of table and insert and before finishing , the 2nd api call is getting fired and datbase lose track of max value of tabled index and key duplication error appears. How to solve this problem in angular ? How can the 2nd call wait until the first call is finishes or other suggestions  ?

```
                for (let key of keys) {                              
                            this.activationService
                                .retrieveActivationKey(                                        
                                    this.siteName,
                                    this.hardwareId                                        
                                )
                                .subscribe({
                                    next: (resp) => {                                         
                                        this.startProcess(resp.Message.Key);   //before first call finish 2nd one starts and issue....                                        
                                    },
                                    error: (err) => {
                                        console.log(`err-->${err}`);                                          
                                    },
                                });
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do by using recursion

```
i:number =0
serverCall() {
            this.activationService.retrieveActivationKey(this.siteName, this.hardwareId)
                .subscribe({
                    next: (resp) => {
                        this.i++;
                        this.startProcess(resp.Message.Key);
                        if (this.i != keys.length) {
                            serverCall();
                        }

                    },
                    error: (err) => {
                        console.log(`err-->${err}`);
                        this.i++;
                        if (this.i != keys.length) {
                            serverCall();
                        }
                    },
                });
       }
```

Comment: Hi Chowdhury,thanks for the workaround. Inside the error block, couple of thoughts , a) Does this capture the err occurred inside 'this.startProcess(resp.Message.Key)' ? b) If yes, do we still need to increment the index (i++) ?  Otherwise the solution i tested OK as it did not reach the error block, which I wanted to verify as well

Comment: No it will not capture error inside this.startProcess(resp.Message.Key), It will capture error only for this.activationService.retrieveActivationKey().subscribe().

Comment: We  don't require to increment  i in startProcess(resp.Message.Key) because we have already done before we call the startProcess(). If it worked you please marked as right answer

Comment: Thanks, my 2nd question was, inside the error block, do we still need to increment the index ? Sorry for not clarifying earlier ?   error: (err) => {
                        console.log(`err-->${err}`);
                        this.i++;
                        if (this.i != keys.length) {
                            serverCall();
                        }
                    },

Comment: yes we need that in error we are calling  function in recursion and variable i used stop the recursion. if i== keys.length recursion  will stop so need to increment i in both resp and error section

Comment: my only concern for the increment was , if we declare i at class level, then why we need to have in both places, meaning ,  even if an error occur, the value is already incremented below next block already , next: (resp) => {             this.i++; , again we attempt to increment inside error block ? Or am i missing something  ?